# Alternatives to Highcharts for datasets with 10k data points?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

We need to generate similar to

http://zopyx.com/tmp/chart.png

Here are the requirements:

- 24*365 data points for the line graph in the upper part of the chart (one value per hour/day for year)
- 12 data points for each block below (one per month)

So each vertical block (one per month) is associated with a set of 24*30 (or 31) datapoints.

I tried to implement the chart using Highcharts but it seems to have serious issue with large data sets (Firefox show an alert about a long running script).

Are there any alternatives to Highcharts that can deal with this usecase? Interactivity is a must (users should be able to zoom-in/out )

Comment: HighCharts v5 is pretty darn fast with [52,000 data points](http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/data-grouping).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've always considered [flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) to be pretty fast with large datasets.  According to my [informal](http://jsfiddle.net/V7RaV/1/) testing with a dataset of 8760 points, chrome (v15) will render it in about 5  seconds, firefox (v8) in about 2 seconds and ie9 is telling me about a 1/2 second (IE < 9 is going to be a no go on speed due to the lack of builtin canvas support).

My one concern for you though, is that >8000 points is crossing the pixel limit of rendering.  Your plot will have to be around 10000 pixels wide to discern any sort of shape.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried google charts plugin? here is the website for a demo : http://www.maxb.net/scripts/jgcharts/include/demo/#1

the API is also easy to use :
http://code.google.com/apis/chart/